# Installing rJava on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, r

I cannot get rJava to install (see log below). I have scoured google and have attempted to resolve this by installing the following packages to no avail:

- libxml2-dev
- libcairo2-dev
- libsqlite-dev
- libmariadbd-dev
- libmariadb-client-lgpl-dev
- libpq-dev
- default-jdk
- libicu-dev
- libbz2-dev
- liblzma-dev

I run `R CMD javareconf` before trying to install rJava and get the following output:

```
Java interpreter : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java
Java version     : 11.0.4
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
Java compiler    : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI program
detected JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o conftest.so conftest.o -L/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server -ljvm -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR


JAVA_HOME        : /usr/lib/jvm/default-java
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include/linux
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/server -ljvm
Updating Java configuration in /usr/lib/R
Done.
```

Then, when I try to install rJava, I get:

```
> install.packages('rJava')
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/rJava_0.9-11.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 675188 bytes (659 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 659 KB

* installing *source* package ‘rJava’ ...
** package ‘rJava’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/wait.h that is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for string.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/time.h usability... yes
checking sys/time.h presence... yes
checking for sys/time.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
checking whether time.h and sys/time.h may both be included... yes
configure: checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 supports static inline...
yes
checking whether setjmp.h is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking whether sigsetjmp is declared... yes
checking whether siglongjmp is declared... yes
checking Java support in R... present:
interpreter : '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java'
archiver    : '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/jar'
compiler    : '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javac'
header prep.: '/usr/bin/javah'
cpp flags   : '-I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux'
java libs   : '-L/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server -ljvm'
checking whether Java run-time works... yes
checking whether -Xrs is supported... yes
checking whether -Xrs will be used... yes
checking whether JNI programs can be compiled... yes
checking whether JNI programs run... yes
checking JNI data types... ok
checking whether JRI should be compiled (autodetect)... yes
checking whether debugging output should be enabled... no
checking whether memory profiling is desired... no
checking whether threads support is requested... no
checking whether callbacks support is requested... no
checking whether JNI cache support is requested... no
checking whether headless init is enabled... no
checking whether JRI is requested... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
config.status: creating R/zzz.R
config.status: creating src/config.h
=== configuring in jri (/tmp/RtmpzTj1AJ/R.INSTALL1667eb1d2f2/rJava/jri)
configure: running /bin/bash ./configure --disable-option-checking '--prefix=/usr/local'  --cache-file=/dev/null --srcdir=.
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking Java version... 11.0.4
checking Java compatibility version (integer)... 11
checking whether /usr/bin/javah actually works... yes
checking for target flags...  -target 1.6 -source 1.6
checking whether Java interpreter works... checking whether JNI programs can be compiled... yes
checking whether JNI programs can be run... yes
checking JNI data types... ok
checking whether Rinterface.h exports R_CStackXXX variables... yes
checking whether Rinterface.h exports R_SignalHandlers... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating run
config.status: creating src/config.h
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c Rglue.c -o Rglue.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c arrayc.c -o arrayc.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c callJNI.c -o callJNI.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c callback.c -o callback.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fields.c -o fields.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c init.c -o init.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c jri_glue.c -o jri_glue.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c loader.c -o loader.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c otables.c -o otables.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c rJava.c -o rJava.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux    -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c tools.c -o tools.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o rJava.so Rglue.o arrayc.o callJNI.o callback.o fields.o init.o jri_glue.o loader.o otables.o rJava.o tools.o -L/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server -ljvm -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
(cd ../jri && make)
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/RtmpzTj1AJ/R.INSTALL1667eb1d2f2/rJava/jri'
make -C src JRI.jar
make[2]: Entering directory '/tmp/RtmpzTj1AJ/R.INSTALL1667eb1d2f2/rJava/jri/src'
/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javac -target 1.6 -source 1.6 -d . ../package-info.java ../RFactor.java ../REXP.java ../Rengine.java ../Mutex.java ../RConsoleOutputStream.java ../RMainLoopCallbacks.java ../RVector.java ../RBool.java ../RList.java
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 6
warning: [options] source value 6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] target value 1.6 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
4 warnings
if [ -n "/usr/bin/javah" ]; then /usr/bin/javah -d . -classpath . org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine; fi
gcc -std=gnu99 -c -o Rengine.o Rengine.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/share/R/include
gcc -std=gnu99 -c -o jri.o jri.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/share/R/include
gcc -std=gnu99 -c -o Rcallbacks.o Rcallbacks.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/share/R/include
gcc -std=gnu99 -c -o Rinit.o Rinit.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/share/R/include -I/usr/share/R/include
gcc -std=gnu99 -c -o globals.o globals.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux
gcc -std=gnu99 -c -o rjava.o rjava.c -g -Iinclude  -DRIF_HAS_CSTACK -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-uuRxut/r-base-3.6.1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux  -fpic -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux
rjava.c: In function ‘RJava_request_lock’:
rjava.c:22:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   write(ipcout, buf, sizeof(ptrlong));
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
rjava.c: In function ‘RJava_clear_lock’:
rjava.c:30:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   write(ipcout, buf, sizeof(ptrlong));
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
rjava.c: In function ‘RJava_request_callback’:
rjava.c:39:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   write(ipcout, buf, sizeof(ptrlong) * 3);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
rjava.c: In function ‘RJava_init_ctrl’:
rjava.c:51:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘write’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   write(ipcout, buf, sizeof(ptrlong));
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
rjava.c:52:3: warning: ignoring return value of ‘read’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   read(resin, buf, sizeof(ptrlong) * 2);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
gcc -std=gnu99 -o libjri.so Rengine.o jri.o Rcallbacks.o Rinit.o globals.o rjava.o  -shared -L/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server -ljvm -Wl,--export-dynamic -fopenmp -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR -lpcre2-8 -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -lrt -ldl -lm -licuuc -licui18n
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcre2-8
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile.all:35: recipe for target 'libjri.so' failed
make[2]: *** [libjri.so] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/tmp/RtmpzTj1AJ/R.INSTALL1667eb1d2f2/rJava/jri/src'
Makefile.all:19: recipe for target 'src/JRI.jar' failed
make[1]: *** [src/JRI.jar] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/RtmpzTj1AJ/R.INSTALL1667eb1d2f2/rJava/jri'
Makevars:14: recipe for target 'jri' failed
make: *** [jri] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rJava’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpPyjqqk/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("rJava") :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any ideas about what else I should try?

Comment: Start with the beginning. The Error Messages are pretty straightforward: "`*** cannot create /usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf.new *** Please run as root if required.`" Check if you have permissions to write in the `/usr/lib/R/etc/` Folder. And, as indicated, run it as the `root` User.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I had run it as root before. I forgot to the time time I captured the output, but I reran `R CMD javareconf` as root again just in case and did not get the errors. I get the same messages when I try to install rJava.

Comment: Fishy. We can see that you have edited your question. So before your edit, there were some errors, while now there are no errors. But you have run the `R CMD javareconf` Command as the `root` User both times. Where is the difference? Why now there are no errors? Anyway, now you have got to the next step. You seem to have a Linker Error this time: `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpcre2-8`. Try to find your `pcre2-8` Library Binary File. It is extremely difficult to debug things like this. Usually, Remote Desktop Connection Sessions are preferred. Your Issue is not trivial.

Comment: I'm sorry. I did not mean to do anything fishy, just to clarify. This is my first question, so I appreciate the feedback about how to best use the site.

I also apparently wasn't very clear: Here is the order of operations on running `R CMD javareconf`:
1) Ran it as root after installing packages via apt-get
2) Tried to install rJava and got errors.
3) Wanted to capture the output of `R CMD javareconf` for posting here, so I reran it but forgot to do it as root and got the error in the original version of the post.
4) Reran it as root and got the version of the output in the current post

Comment: What do you mean by "Remote Desktop Connection Sessions" are preferred?

Comment: All right. So the step (3) explains the intricacy of the current description. What can we say? Software Installations are usually done using a certain Software Installation Plan, not blindly. If you do not have a Software Installation Plan Document that you can follow, then you may try to find some kind of Tutorial Web-Pages that might help you in performing your Software Installation Procedure. Random actions usually lead to intricate situations like the current one, which are really difficult to debug. It is difficult to track the cause of the issue this way.

Comment: Remote Desktop Connection Sessions are of course outside of the scope of this Web-Site, but are naturally handier under these circumstances. We cannot help you that way.

Comment: Ok. That's good to hear. It did not seem appropriate to suggest a remote desktop connection, so I assumed you must have meant something else by that.

Comment: I do have an image of the machine before I began the install process, so if there were a good installation guide available, I could follow that. Unfortunately, I have not found one that has worked so far.

Comment: This must be maybe the fourth or the fifth time when we have been uttering these words on this Web-Site, but we believe that you have to find an Expert in the `R` Statistical Programming Language. Try to find an `R`-related Community that might help you during your quest.

Comment: I'm sorry to have made you repeat yourself.

Comment: We did not mean it to sound like that. It was a simple notice to ourselves. Unfortunately, we have no experience in the `R` World. It is also very rare when an `R` Expert comes floating around over here. Leave the question open. Improve it with any kind of findings that you may have come across about it. And maybe somebody else with greater `R` muscles than ourselves will be coming by in order to help. Good luck in your quest!

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: Thanks! I actually thought for some reason that my low reputation as a new user prevented me from posting answers anywhere. Don't know where I got that idea!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by downgrading R from 3.6 to 3.4. I discovered this solution by attempting to install rJava through aptitude. I cannot find any documentation stating that rJava is incompatible with R 3.6, and I have rJava installed with R 3.5 on a Mac, so this does not seem like an ideal solution, but it is sufficient for my current needs.

```
$ sudo aptitude install r-cran-rjava
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  r-cran-rjava{b}
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 19 not upgraded.
Need to get 557 kB of archives. After unpacking 1704 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-cran-rjava : Depends: r-api-3.4 which is a virtual package, provided by:
                         - r-base-core (3.4.4-1ubuntu1), but 3.6.1-3bionic is installed

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     r-cran-rjava [Not Installed]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Downgrade the following packages:
1)      r-base [3.6.1-3bionic (now) -> 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 (bionic)]
2)      r-base-core [3.6.1-3bionic (now) -> 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 (bionic)]
3)      r-cran-boot [1.3-23-2bionic0 (now) -> 1.3-20-1.1 (bionic)]
4)      r-cran-class [7.3-15-1bionic0 (now) -> 7.3-14-2build1 (bionic)]
5)      r-cran-cluster [2.1.0-2bionic0 (now) -> 2.0.6-2build1 (bionic)]
6)      r-cran-codetools [0.2-16-1bionic0 (now) -> 0.2-15-1.1 (bionic)]
7)      r-cran-foreign [0.8.72-1bionic0 (now) -> 0.8.69-1build1 (bionic)]
8)      r-cran-kernsmooth [2.23-15-3cranArtful0~ubuntu18.04.1~ppa1 (now) -> 2.23-15-3build1 (bionic)]
9)      r-cran-mass [7.3-51.4-2bionic0 (now) -> 7.3-49-1 (bionic)]
10)     r-cran-matrix [1.2-17-2bionic0 (now) -> 1.2-12-1 (bionic)]
11)     r-cran-nlme [3.1.141-1bionic0 (now) -> 3.1.131-3build1 (bionic)]
12)     r-cran-nnet [7.3-12-2cranArtful0~ubuntu18.04.1~ppa1 (now) -> 7.3-12-2build1 (bionic)]
13)     r-cran-rpart [4.1-15-2bionic0 (now) -> 4.1-13-1 (bionic)]
14)     r-cran-spatial [7.3-11-2cranArtful0~ubuntu18.04.1~ppa1 (now) -> 7.3-11-2build1 (bionic)]
15)     r-cran-survival [2.44-1.1-2bionic0 (now) -> 2.41-3-2build1 (bionic)]
16)     r-recommended [3.6.1-3bionic (now) -> 3.4.4-1ubuntu1 (bionic)]
```

Answer (score -1):

On 18.04 and [R] version 3.6, I did the following 
`sudo apt-get install libpcre2-dev`

following instructions from this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59969845/problems-with-installation-of-rjava-in-linux-mint-19-3-mate

rJava was installed successfully.